# About Windows Interactive services Security

Tags: windows, defense

I know most services run under non interactive windows station or desktop also called session 0 while as some services (interactive) running under local system account create a window on interactive desktop and access the User desktop by calling **OpenWindowstation** and **GetThreadDesktop** functions.  It often displays **UIOdetect**, a method of inter-process communication so the user can interact with it.

Can this, and other inter-process communication like **named pipes**, expose the service interface over the network? Could this be a security risk?  How can we set appropriate ACL's during interactive service configuration to save ourselves?